# How to select a row through a join if a column in the joined table has value 0 or does not exist

Tags: mysql, join

Important to know, I'm working with legacy data here, so I can't restructure the data.

And then the question, I have 3 tables: categories, records, and special status. Now I need a query that will result in finding all the categories, always, but I only need to the records if they have a certain special status. My problem is, not all records have a special status, but not having one equals the status 0 (which means "open"). So, how do I find all the "open" records? Either based on the fact that no corresponding special_status row exists or that the status value in that row = 0?

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `position` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `records` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `special_status` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The relationship between the categories and the records is obvious. The one between records and special_status is based on *special_status.parent_id = records.id AND special_status.type = 2*.

### Here you find a working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ea7fc/4).

But, with a wrong query (based on an answer I received). I get to many records while I only need the "open" records (special_status.status = 0  or there is no existing corresponding special_status row). Below is the result that I'm expecting (between parentheses are the record ids that showed up with the faulty query).

```
cat record              status
1   11          Title C false
1   13          Title E (null)
1   14          Title F false
1   (null)      (null)  (null) (18)
2   (null)      (null)  (null) (9)
2   (null)      (null)  (null) (12)
3   (null)      (null)  (null)
4   (null)      (null)  (null)
5   (null)      (null)  (null)
6   (null)      (null)  (null)
7   (null)      (null)  (null)
8   (null)      (null)  (null)
9   (null)      (null)  (null)
10  10          Title B (null)
11  (null)      (null)  (null)
12  15          Title G (null)
12  16          Title H (null)
12  17          Title I (null)
```

Comment: You can try in this way SELECT categories.id, categories.position,records.id, records.title, special_status.status 
   FROM testing.categories
   INNER JOIN testing.records on records.id=categories.id
   INNER JOIN testing.special_status on special_status.parent_id = records.id 
       AND special_status.type = 2;   or update some dumy data and check

Comment: This only gives me the categories that have records with a special status, no mater which special status.While I need a full list of all the categories with their records IF the records have no special status or special status = 0, or null instead of records if no matching records were found.

Comment: Can you create SQLFiddle  with dumy data?

Comment: I got the Fiddle online Piyush

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want all data from records and special_status whether they match or not with categories. So "LEFT JOIN" looks appropriate. According to W3School

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

In this case, your query goes something like this.

```sql
SELECT categories.id, categories.position,records.id, 
   records.title, special_status.status 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN records 
  ON records.cat_id=categories.id 
LEFT JOIN special_status 
  ON special_status.parent_id = records.id 
AND special_status.type = 2;
```

### [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ab8c3/5) is working Fiddle.

Comment: Again, this results in finding all the records with whatever status they have. I need a way to find only those records that have either status = 0 OR that have no row in special_status, yet keeping the complete list of the categories intact. I'm currently working on my own Fiddle with more dummy data to better illustrate the problem.